# Use index to filter user by age limit calculate

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, sql-function

Consider this example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_age(date_of_birth DATE) 
RETURN NUMBER AS
BEGIN
  RETURN 
    TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, date_of_birth)/12);
END
```

Because get_age() is non deterministic, so the problem is that if I create index for function get_age() but index won't update the new age and when querying the data will be wrong.

How can i still use an index to optimize a query for get user with input age?

Initially, I was tried create index column date_of_birth, afterward I was calculator date by C# and query like

```
Select * from User
where date_of_birth between DateTime.Today.AddYears(-42)
                        and DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).AddYears(-43)
```

but my instructor thought that doing so would require a lot of repetitive calculations. So is there any way to limit the repeated calculation?

Comment: _repetitive calculations_ - where? What does the explain output say?

Comment: Creating an index on age is sort of like trying to create an index on the current time. It'll keep changing and you would need to update it once a day.

The way you suggested is correct. There won't be any repetitive calculations on the database side.

Comment: I think my instructor wants the optimized condition in between, because every time a request comes in, it will have to recalculate the condition in between.

Comment: @mikkel I think so, too but my instructor don't want to the recalculation in between

Comment: `select * from User where date_of_birth between @fromdate and @fromdate+365` then? You need two dates no matter how and I would choose to calculate those dates in c# rather than in SQL

Comment: @mikkel yeah, I has been calulate date in c#, and DateTime.Today.AddYears(-42) or DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).AddYears(-43) are from c#. I intentionally written like that to make it recognizable c#

Comment: That SQL you have isn't valid T-SQL, are you sure you're using SQL Server?